# Using CakePHP to build web apps with subdomains

Tags: php, cakephp

I am building a web app using CakePHP that will allow users to create subdomains for their company / organisations. For example `company-name.domain.com`

To achieve this I have a Users table and a Subsites table like so:

Users: id, username, email, password, subsite_id
Subsites: id, name, domain

As you can see Users are linked to subsites and subsites can have many users through this relationship, but users can only belong to one subsite.

I check if a subdomain is valid using the following in AppController:

```
function checkSubdomain()
{
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'domain.com')
    {
        $domain_parts = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        if (count($domain_parts) != 3) exit('Invalid url');

        $subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

        $this->loadModel('Subsite');

        $subsites = $this->Subsite->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('domain'=>$subdomain)));

        if(empty($subsites))
        {
            exit('Subsite not found');
        }
    }
}

function beforeFilter()
{
    $this->checkSubdomain();
}
```

This basically says if a subdomain IS NOT found then error out, which works fine! The problem I have is that I want certain pages like home, about, pricing and signup forms to not be accessible for subdomains for obvious reasons.

What would be the best way of doing this? Without having to a check in all my controllers if it's a subdomain or not?

I've noticed that other apps like getballpark.com use a subdomain for the signup process. Is their a special way to allow certain subdomains to have certain pages?

Thanks

**Additional requirements based on the answer below that blocks access to certain controllers if a subdomain is being used:**

One other problem is that I use the HomeController to either show a splash promo page or the dashboard for the app if the user is logged in. The problem is how do I say you must ONLY be logged in for that method if you are accessing via a subdomain. Or is their an entirely better solution for achieving the sam functionality.

In protecting the signup (which is in my UsersController) I'd also be blocking the login and forgot password methods. How do I get around this without having to break Cake convention and move methods to individual controllers? Cheers

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, you want URLs like `company-name.domain.com/signup` to be inaccessible? Am I right assuming that all the subdomains are linked to the main domain where all the magic is handled by a single application?

Comment: Yes single application. Am I wrong to do this?

Comment: No, It's fine, I just wanted to make sure what your environment looks like before suggesting a solution.

Comment: Oh and what Cake version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making a list of forbidden controllers, and then checking against that in the app controllers `beforeFilter` handler in case the current request comes from a subdomain:

```
protected $_forbiddenSubdomainControllers = array
(
    'about',
    'home',
    'pricing',
    'signup'
);

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if($this->checkSubdomain() &&
       in_array($this->request->params['controller'], $this->_forbiddenSubdomainControllers))
    {
        throw new ForbiddenException('This URL is inaccessible');
    }

}

public function checkSubdomain()
{
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'domain.com')
    {
        $domain_parts = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        if (count($domain_parts) != 3) exit('Invalid url');

        $subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

        $this->loadModel('Subsite');

        $subsites = $this->Subsite->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('domain'=>$subdomain)));

        if(empty($subsites))
        {
            throw new NotFoundException('Subsite not found');
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that i've changed your `checkSubdomain` method so that it returns `true` or `false` depeding on whether the request comes form a (valid) subdomain, and i've also changed your `exit` call to throwing an error, which is the prefered way in CakePHP to handle such situations.

If you want to allow certain subdomains to use some of these "special" controllers, then i'd suggest to store the allowed controllers in the database and associate them to the `Subsite` model, then you can include these names in the check.

---

**Edit (05.11.2012)**

Requiring authentication for specific controlls only when requested from a subdomain, could for example be achieved by using [`AuthComponent::allow`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#AuthComponent%3a%3aallow). In the `Home` controllers `beforeFilter` callback you could check for the subdomain, and then allow/deny non authenticated access appropriately. For example allow all actions in case the request doesn't come from a subdomain:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if(!$this->checkSubdomain())
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
}
```

With your new requirements in mind to restrict access to specific actions, i'd say that depending on the complexity of your application, restricting/granting access might be a job for [ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html).

Doing it "manually" instead, my first example could be extended with actions, for example like this:

```
protected $_denyAccessMap = array
(
    'about',
    'home',
    'pricing',
    'users' => array
    (
        'signup'
    )
);

public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if($this->checkSubdomain())
    {
        $controller = $this->request->params['controller'];
        $action = $this->request->params['action'];

        if(in_array($controller, $this->_denyAccessMap) ||
          (array_key_exists($controller, $this->_denyAccessMap) && in_array($action, $this->_denyAccessMap[$controller])))
        {
            throw new ForbiddenException('This URL is inaccessible');
        }
    }
}
```

That would deny access to the controllers `about`, `home` and `pricing`, and to the `users` controller `signup` action.

As already mentioned, this could also be done using ACL, and since you said that you need to grant certain subdomains more acceess, this might be the better option, it would allow you to dynamically control the access restrictions. Have a look at the [Simple Acl controlled Application tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html), you could easily use this, you'd just need to replace the `Group` model with your `Subsite` model.

That way you could grant specific subsites, and therefore the users associated with that subsites, access to specific actions, for example allow the `Subsite` with the `id` `1` access to all controllers, except for the `Users` controllers `subscribe` method:

```
$this->Subsite->id = 1;

$this->Acl->allow($this->Subsite, 'controllers');
$this->Acl->deny($this->Subsite, 'controllers/User/subscribe');
```

Or the other way around, block access to the `Users` controller, expect for the specific `login` and `passwordRecovery` actions:

```
$this->Acl->allow($this->Subsite, 'controllers');
$this->Acl->deny($this->Subsite, 'controllers/User');
$this->Acl->allow($this->Subsite, 'controllers/User/login');
$this->Acl->allow($this->Subsite, 'controllers/User/passwordRecovery');
```

Checking whether access is allowed could then for example be done in the app controllers `beforeFilter` callback:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $subsite = $this->checkSubdomain();
    if(!empty($subsite))
    {
        $aco = 'controllers/' . $this->name . '/' . $this->request->params['action'];
        if($this->Acl->check($subsite, $aco))
        {
            throw new ForbiddenException('This URL is inaccessible');
        }
    }
}

public function checkSubdomain()
{
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'domain.com')
    {
        $domain_parts = explode('.',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);

        if (count($domain_parts) != 3) exit('Invalid url');

        $subdomain = $domain_parts[0];

        $this->loadModel('Subsite');

        $subsite = $this->Subsite->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('domain'=>$subdomain)));

        if(empty($subsite))
        {
            throw new NotFoundException('Subsite not found');
        }

        return $subsite;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that i've changed the `checkSubdomain` method so that it returns the `find` result or `false` so that it can easily be used for the ACL check.

Comment: I'd suggest that you update your question with these new requirements, there's a little more space for explanations, and it's easier to follow for others when I update my answer with suggestions and examples for these requirements.

Comment: Hey. Added the requirements to my question. Look forward to your responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the main question & answer, I would take into consideration development environments as well... Since I had a similar problem few days ago, I worked on it and here is what I did :

Inside the AppController :

```
function checkAccess() {
    if (count($domain_parts) != 3 &&
       (count($domain_parts) == 2 && $domain_parts[1] != 'localhost:8080')) {
        throw new NotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Inside checkSubdomain() method :

```
checkSubdomain() {

    [...]

    $this->checkAccess();

    [...]

}
```

Since I was testing the subdomain funcionality on localhost, I could use xxx.localhost and yyy.localhost and check everything was ok before deploy.